# How to store dynamic/multiple attributes of a entity

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm building a web application with Laravel where users can search locations based on proximity and attribute filters and now I was wondering on what is a good schema for storing the attributes.

For example, users can create a listing for a restaurant and then should be able to add information on what payment options are accepted by the restaurant (cash, card, maybe even paypal), what type of restaurant it is (fast food, dinner, lunchroom) or what type(s) of kitchen they have (Mexican, Italian, French).

**I would like to build a solution where:**

- Attributes are not obligatory, the admin doesn't have to fill in all attributes
- Locations van have multiple values attribute, for example in a restaurant you can pay cash and card
- The solution fits Laravel's 'way of thinking'. I would love to have it play together with Eloquent nicely

*I came up with some solutions on how to solve this, but I'm not sure which is the best and if there maybe is an even better solution?*

**Option 1**

Serialize everything on the location table itself, for example in a column 'attributes'. This seems a 'lazy way' to do it because maintainin/updating locations would be really hard and searching/filtering even more.

**Option 2**

Have a different table for every attribute with all the values and a *many to many* relationship with locations. For example a table *payment_methods*:

```
-----------------------------
| id |  name  | description |
-----------------------------
|  1 |  cash  | ......      |
-----------------------------
|  2 |  card  | ......      |
-----------------------------
|  3 | paypal | ......      |
-----------------------------
```

And a pivot table that links the payment options to locations

```
----------------------------------
| id |  payment_id  | location_d |
----------------------------------
|  1 |       1      |     1      |
----------------------------------
|  2 |       2      |     1      |
----------------------------------
|  3 |       1      |     2      |
----------------------------------
```

Now all the values are stored in a table so admins can easily add possible options and this is easy to maintain in laravel with Eloquent

```
\App\Location::with('paymentMethods')->...
```

But the problem is that for every type of attribute I need to add a migration and the database would clutter up with tables like *payment_methods*, *kitchen_types* & *restaurant_types*. I think this wouldn't be that maintainable as well since you need to write a new admin interface and migration for every new attribute.

**Option 3**

Have one table (*product_attributes*) with all the attributes, values and descriptions. One could group the attributes with the attribute value as a property on the location and it's values as an array.

```
------------------------------------------------
| id |    attribute    |  value  | description |
------------------------------------------------
|  1 |  payment_method |  cash   | ......      |
------------------------------------------------
|  2 |  payment_method |  card   | ......      |
------------------------------------------------
|  3 |  payment_method |  PayPal | ......      |
------------------------------------------------
|  4 |   kitchen_type  |  French | ......      |
------------------------------------------------
|  5 |   kitchen_type  | Italian | ......      |
------------------------------------------------
|  6 |   kitchen_type  | Mexican | ......      |
------------------------------------------------
```

And a pivot table that links the payment options to locations

```
--------------------------------------------
| id |  product_attribute_id  | location_d |
--------------------------------------------
|  1 |            1           |     1      |
--------------------------------------------
|  2 |            2           |     1      |
--------------------------------------------
|  3 |            3           |     2      |
--------------------------------------------
```

All the values are stored in one table and admins also can add options and new attributes right now. There is no need for adding new tables, so that seems cleaner to me. The problem right seems to be more about one table cluttering up with all kinds of information/attributes.

Also I was wondering on how to retrieve the data from the database via Eloquent in the following format:

```
$location->attributes->attribute_name = ['value1', 'value2']
```

For example

```
$location = \App\Location::with('productAttributes')->find($id);

$location->attributes->payment_methods = ['Cash']
$location->attributes->kitchen_types = ['French', 'Italian']
```

Can anyone please advise me on what is a good solution in my situation? To me the last option (3) seems to be the most appropriate since you can store all sorts of attributes without the need to add multiple tables on new attributes. But maybe there are other options which are even better?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with 2nd option with no doubt. It means a bit more of managin on the DB and maybe a couple more screens on the app. On the other hand is maintainable and if you decide to grow up any of the tables (tax for payment methods for example) you would only have to modify one table and the changes would be relevant to it. Also if you consider the part of Laravel where a Model relates to a table, then there is yet another point to do it separetly. The down side that you might find is if the relations betwen tables gets really messy or complicated eloquent can not be as easy and straight forward as with less tables, but still usable.

Hope to have helped, but is just my opinion here ;)

Comment: Thanks for your advise, really appreciated! Is it still possible to have all the different attributes under one key on the object? like: $location->attributes->payment_methods. And also, wouldn't it be to harder on the DB when you laravel has to join 15 tables on the locations table instead of 1?

Comment: I do not see the need of adding the intermediate level of 'attrivutes' for your locations. Anything in the location model would be and can be an attribute itself. I think that this would add complexity to your models and app for no real benefit.

Regarding the tables relations it depends on the relation betwen them, if it's a one to many is easy. It gets hard when they have nested relations in the models

Comment: But then for every new attribute you need 2 tables, one for storing the values and a pivot table for managing the relations. So if there would be 10 attributes, you have to create 20 tables... To me that looks a bit overkill

Comment: What is the reason for adding all the attributes separetly and not inside the Location model?

Comment: I don't really get what you mean by that? I thought you meant to create different tables/models for all attribute types and then create relationships between the location model and the attribute models. Since a location can have more attributes of the same type (multiple payment options) I thought I'd use a many to many relationship. I could also store every value in a single table (id - location_id - name - description) but then I still need a lookup table where all possible values for the payment methods are stored.

Comment: Yeah, sorry (little lapsus here :) ). I still think that having multiple tables is the best option. It sounds like a pain in the ass having soo many tables but at the end you probably wouldn't add another 20 attributes. If not you could try to create a single pivot table with a 3rd column definig the table that relates to, but that might complicate eloquent a bit :(